# About the definition of flat twisted sheaves

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, sheaf-theory, flatness

Flat twisted sheaves are mentioned in [Căldăraru's thesis](http://www.math.wisc.edu/~andreic/publications/ThesisSingleSpaced.pdf) (Lemma 2.1.2 for example), but I'm confused about how they should be defined. I have in mind some possibilities, given an $\alpha$-twisted sheaf $\mathcal F \in \operatorname{Mod}(X,\alpha)$:

1. The functor $\mathcal F \otimes - \colon \operatorname{Mod}(X,\beta) \to \operatorname{Mod}(X,\alpha \beta)$ is exact for all $\beta$ in the Brauer group of $X$.
2. The functor $\mathcal F \otimes - \colon \operatorname{Mod}(X) \to \operatorname{Mod}(X,\alpha)$ is exact.
3. The functor $\mathcal F \otimes - \colon \operatorname{Mod}(X,\alpha^{-1}) \to \operatorname{Mod}(X)$ is exact.
4. Writing $\mathcal F = (\mathcal F_i, \varphi_{ij})$ on some cover $\mathfrak U = \{ U_i \}$, $\mathcal F_i$ is a flat $\mathcal O_{U_i}$-module for all $i$.

Are those conditions equivalent? Or perhaps none of them is the correct definition?

Comment: 2,3,4 seem all equivalent to me, by viewing a-twisted sheaves (and more generally a^k-twisted sheaves) as sheaves on the total stack of the gerbe a

Comment: What about the first one?